# Examples of using a recursive Ivy deliver or publish

Tags: ivy

Does anyone have specific examples of using the Ivy `<deliver>` or `<publish>` tasks with the `delivertarget` attribute to do recursive deliveries?  The official documentation is rather...sparse.  Are there any guidelines for when to use it rather than normal Ant "parent" build mechanisms (e.g., `<subant>`) to do the recursion?

Comment: This should be a very common problem, but there is surprisingly little out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help: http://marc.info/?l=ivy-user&m=122191102120241

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why my Googling didn't find that but it's pretty much what I expected.